# Row size too large when we try to update the table

Tags: mysql

When I add data to my database the following error occurs:

> row size too large. the maximum row size for the used table type, not counting blobs, is 8126. you have to change some columns to text or blobs

In my database there are 250 fields, how can I solve this error?

When I change all fields to BLOBs, the same error occurs.

Comment: Why do you have a table with 250 columns? It's not normal.

Comment: 250 fields o_0! Read about database normalization.

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* preserve this many-column table, try switching the storage engine you use for the table from InnoDB to MyISAM.

But the comments are correct: 250 columns is undoubtedly a sign of a strangely designed table. The expensive RDBMS products (Oracle, etc) will probably handle this scenario better if you must go into production with that table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html describes the limits on the contents of rows.

Before you do something like changing *all* fields from varchar(n) to BLOB, you probably want to examine the purpose of the table. BLOB fields are slow.